# How to make execvp() handle multiple arguments?

Tags: c++, linux, shell

I have a problem with `execvp()` in C++.  Here is my code:

```
char * argv[]={};
command_counter = 0; 
char line[255];
fgets(line,255,stdin);

argv[0] = strtok(line, TOKEN);//seperate the command with TOKEN




while (arg = strtok(NULL, TOKEN)) {
        ++command_counter;
        cout << command_counter << endl;
        argv[command_counter] = arg;
        cout << argv[command_counter] << endl;
    }
argv[++command_counter] = (char *) NULL;
execvp(argv[0],argv);
```

But the problem is, multiple arguments are not working when I use `execvp()` like this.

Like `ls -a -l`, it is only executing the `ls -a` as a result.

What's wrong with this program?

With the help of you guys the problem was solved by changing the statement of char * argv[128]

Comment: Nonsense — `execvp()` has no problem handling very large numbers of arguments.  You've got a problem with the way you are using `execvp()`.  You would do yourself a favour by characterizing your problem as "how do I use `execvp()` correctly because this isn't working" rather than "`execvp()` doesn't work".  I've more or less fixed the wording in the question for you, this time, but you will learn over time that you are wrong more often than the system is.

Comment: `char * argv[]={};` What do you think this will do?

Comment: Since your line is 255 characters long, there can't be more than 128 arguments, so you should write: `char * argv[128];`.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Thanks I will change the title of this question

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Thanks buddy the problem is solved..

Comment: @JonathanLeffler But the thing is I don't know why 128 not other number of argv[]?

Comment: You're welcome.  Note that although I said "should", I should have qualified that as "you could write `char *argv[128];` as the simplest fix, but a more general solution will deal with longer lines and more arguments, but is harder to code".  And I explained 'why 128'.  However, in detail, if you have "a b c...\n" fitting inside `char line[255];`, you have at most 127 non-blanks and 126 blanks separating them, plus a newline and a terminal null, so 128 leaves you enough space for a pointer to each argument and the terminal null pointer. Even if the newline wasn't there (truncation), you're OK.

Comment: Thank you very much.. Would you please type the complex solution for me?@JonathanLeffler

Comment: You can type it as the answer..@JonathanLeffler

Comment: @HoweChen You better ask a new question for this - a complex answer for this simple question would be confusing for anyone who reads it in the future. Also, please read [this suggestion](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).

Answer (score 2):

The *first* thing that's wrong with it is that you're creating a zero-sized array to store the arguments:

```
char * argv[]={};
```

then populating it.

That's a big undefined behaviour red flag right there.

A quick and dirty fix would be ensuring you have some space there:

```
char * argv[1000];
```

but, to be honest, that has its own problems if you ever get to the point where you may have more than a thousand arguments.

Bottom line is, you should ensure there's enough space in the array for storing your arguments.

---

*One* way of doing this is with dynamic memory allocation, which expands the array of arguments as needed, so as to ensure there's always enough space:

```
using namespace std;

#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cstdio>
#include <unistd.h>

#define TOKEN " "

static char **addArg (char **argv, size_t *pSz, size_t *pUsed, char *str) {
    // Make sure enough space for another one.

    if (*pUsed == *pSz) {
        *pSz = *pSz + 25;
        argv = (char **) realloc (argv, *pSz * sizeof (char*));
        if (argv == 0) {
            cerr << "Out of memory\n";
            exit (1);
        }
    }

    // Add it and return (possibly new) array.

    argv[(*pUsed)++] = (str == 0) ? 0 : strdup (str);
    return argv;
}

int main (void) {
    Initial size, used and array.

    size_t sz = 0, used = 0;
    char **argv = 0;

    // Temporary pointer and command.

    char *str, line[] = "ls -a -l";

    // Add the command itself.

    argv = addArg (argv, &sz, &used, strtok (line, TOKEN));

    // Add each argument in turn, then the terminator.

    while ((str = strtok (0, TOKEN)) != 0)
        argv = addArg (argv, &sz, &used, str);

    argv = addArg (argv, &sz, &used, 0);

    // Then execute it.

    execvp (argv[0], argv);

    // Shouldn't reach here.

    return 0;
}
```